# how to make a popup chat application without using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have made a dating website where I have use one to one chatting application like facebook. When one user send any message to another user it showing into their popup chat box, but I have done this using ajax. Which I have run in every interval using javascript setInterval function. But I think the process is not optimize one. I don't want to make unnecessary request to the server each time, rather it only trigger when there is some new message for that user. Is there any other way to do it or any other protocol which using by big site like facebook, gmail?

Comment: The usual method is to set your server up to hold the connection open until it has data to send. This is what gmail does (or at least used to do; not sure if it still does). The basic idea is: AJAX request is made, server sends data immediately if it is available, or keeps the request open as long as it can otherwise. When the client gets data back, it immediately sends a new request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this using [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/), but that requires both a server implementation and a web browser that supports it.

Another technique is to use [Long Polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), but again, this requires work on both the client and the server. The advantage is that this is a cross browser compatible technique.

Comment: Thank you Josh. I haven't used that before let me try it and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josh that WebSockets would be worth looking into, however if you don't have access to the server you could use something like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/j4ljaqgronc) for the back end.

https://www.firebase.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Read into [Long Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code). It's what facebook uses. Basically your client makes one Ajax call and nothing gets returned until there is data to push to it. I'm pretty sure it requires some custom server configuration so if you're developing on shared hosting it isn't going to cut it. Long Polling would be the right, albeit, more complicated way of doing this if efficiency is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Server-Sent Events seems to be another option.

A chat example: http://motyar.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/simple-chat-application-with-html5.html
Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events